# Custom delegate not working (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, delegates

I have a custom UITableViewCell subclass which I want to create a delegate for. This is the .h of the UITableViewCell subclass:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class InfoTableViewCell;

@protocol InfoTableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>;

@optional
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title;

@end


@interface InfoTableViewCell : UITableViewCell <UITextFieldDelegate> {

    UITextField *textField;

    NSNumber *objectId;
    NSNumber *cellId;
    NSNumber *isName;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *objectId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *cellId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *isName;

@end
```

However, the app crashes and it says that there is no method called setDelegate: when I call [cell setDelegate:self]; in my UIViewController subclass, which initializes the cell. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May be post code where you create and initialise your cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a delegate property that conforms to the protocol, e.g. like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class InfoTableViewCell;
@protocol InfoTableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>;
@optional
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title;
@end

@interface InfoTableViewCell : UITableViewCell <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    id <InfoTableViewCellDelegate> delegate;
    UITextField *textField;
    NSNumber *objectId;
    NSNumber *cellId;
    NSNumber *isName;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *objectId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *cellId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *isName;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <InfoTableViewCellDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Don't forget to synthesize.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to create a `delegate` attribute and set the property.

```
id <InfoTableViewCellDelegate> delegate;

//...

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <InfoTableViewCellDelegate> delegate;
```

Answer (score 0):

isn't it UITableView that has a delegate, not UITableViewCell?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without more context, but it seems like you want to be doing this instead:

```
textField.delegate = cell;
```